# Woher kommt die Bezeichung »Freundlicher« für einen Kfz-Mechaniker?

Tags: etymology, phrase

In vielen Autoforen ist die Bezeichnung *Freundlicher* synonym zum *Kfz-Mechaniker* oft anzutreffen, z.B.

> Mein Freundlicher hat die Querlenkerbuchsen getauscht.
>
> Frag beim Freundlichen nach, woher dieses Klopfen kommt.

Beispiel [hier](http://rx8forum.de/index.php/Thread/9257-Klopfen-bei-Schlagl%C3%B6chern-Domlager-Kaputt/).

Lässt sich die Herkunft dieser Bezeichnung nachvollziehen? Ist sie eine regionale oder bundesweite Erscheinung?

Comment: Kannst du einen Link auf einen entsprechenden Beitrag posten?

Comment: Schon geschehen

Comment: Findet sich dieses Wort auf verschiedenen Seiten oder nur auf wenigen? Wenn es sich nur auf wenigen Webseiten findet, kann ich mir vorstellen, dass es ein Wort ist, das für die User bestimmter Webseiten typisch ist. (Ich kann mir in diesem Fall auch denken, wie es zu diesem Wort kam.)

Comment: Ich hab es in zahlreichen Internetforen schon gesehen. Auch für unterschiedliche Automarken.

Comment: Nach meinem Wissen war das mal ein Spruch aus einer älteren VW-Werbung, d.h. von VW selbst "erfunden". Ich gucke mal, ob ich einen Beleg finde…

Comment: Zum Thema "regional": Ist mir (BW, Schwaben, Schwarzwald) völlig unbekannt. Und ich arbeite in der Automobilbranche.

Comment: Der (in jedem Auto-Internetforum gängige) Begriff bezieht sich übrigens nicht auf einen einzelnen Mechaniker, sondern auf die Werkstatt/den Händler als Unternehmen. Man würde also eher nicht sagen, „Ich schaute dem Freundlichen bei der Reparatur über die Schulter“, sondern vielmehr „In meiner Verzweiflung brachte ich den Wagen schließlich zum Freundlichen, aber auch der Mechaniker/Meister blätterte nur ratlos in seiner Reparaturanleitung.“

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In vielen Foren ist diese Frage schon gestellt worden, und die übereinstimmende Meinung ist, dass es eine Werbekampagne gab, in der man aufgefordert wurde zu seinem freundlichen XY-Händler zu gehen, wobei die Meinung dominiert, dass dies eine [VW-Kampagne](http://www.motor-talk.de/forum/warum-der-freundliche-t994760.html) war, aber auch [Opel](http://www.motor-talk.de/forum/mal-ne-bloede-frage-woher-kommt-der-begriff-freundlicher-t983335.html) und [BMW](http://www.bmw-syndikat.de/bmwsyndikatforum/topic63334_Warum_heisst_der_BMW-Haendler_Freundlicher__Geplaudere.html) fand ich genannt.

Als Nichtautomobilist war mir diese Begriffsverwendung bis vor 10 Minuten völlig unbekannt obwohl ich seit Jahrzehnten auch PKW-Werbung ausgesetzt bin. Offensichtlich handelt es sich um einen Jargon in einigen Autokreisen, ist aber auch da nicht jedem geläufig wie die vielen Fragen zeigen.